# Creating Carousel View same as apple app Store in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am working with sencha Touch application.
i have used ext.carousel component for different views. 
actually, i want to show **part of my previous and next item card** inside the carousel.
same as **apple app store** like below,
[image]

can anyone suggest me how i can do with my carousel view ? 
also any alternative solution is acceptable.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `itemLength` for Carousel.. that's it.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
            fullscreen: true,
             itemLength: 250, // change value as you want
            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            }, 
            items: [
                {
                    html: 'red',
                    style: 'background-color:#f00;'
                }, {
                    html: 'orange',
                    style: 'background-color:#ffb600;'
                }, {
                    html: 'yellow',
                    style: 'background-color:#ff0;'
                }, {
                    html: 'green',
                    style: 'background-color:#80ff4d;'
                }, {
                    html: 'blue',
                    style: 'background-color:#009dff;'
                }
            ] 
        });
```